# How to subset data frame using information from a matrix?

Tags: r

I would like to be able to do the following: read the coefficient matrix CF and identify which variables have non-zero coefficient (in this example var2 and var4). Then create a new data frame or matrix containing only these variables.

Thank you!

```r
# Dataframe
var1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
var2 <- c(1, 0.3, 1.2)
var3 <- c(6, 8, 11)
var4 <- c(0.2, 4, 11)
df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)

# Matrix with coefficients for the variables in df
CF <- as.matrix(c(0.0, 0.9, 0.0, -1.2))
rownames(CF) <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")


# Desired result is dataframe or matrix 
df_var <- data.frame(var2, var4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a logical vector, get the `row.names` from 'CF' and use that as column names in 'df'

```
df_var <- df[row.names(CF)[CF != 0]]
```

-output

```
df_var
  var2 var4
1  1.0  0.2
2  0.3  4.0
3  1.2 11.0
```